# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot connect to Canon Pixma MP560 Printer?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, printers

Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04
Printer: Canon Pixma MP560

I try to add printer in ubuntu. I used find printer but when I type in the printers IP address in host and click probe then nothing happens.

How do I get this printer to communicate with printer?

Answer (score 2):

I installed this. Then when adding the printer, the printer was picked up automatically:

```
apt-cache search bjnp
sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp
```